# Opengl es render to textture appears upside down

Tags: opengl-es

Using frame buffer 
When rendering the texture appears upsidedown, here are vertices and texture coordinate.
By the way rendering without creating frame buffer renders the texture correctely

```
private final float[] mVerticesData =
    { 
            -1f, 1f, 0.0f, // Position 0
            0.0f, 0.0f, // TexCoord 0
            -1f, -1f, 0.0f, // Position 1
            0.0f, 1.0f, // TexCoord 1
            1f, -1f, 0.0f, // Position 2
            1.0f, 1.0f, // TexCoord 2
            1f, 1f, 0.0f, // Position 3
            1.0f, 0.0f // TexCoord 3
    };
```

Any help please ...
thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When uploading 2D texture images to OpenGL, it expects the data to be specified from bottom to top, even though usually images are in memory from top to bottom. You seem to have inverted your texture coordinates to work around this problem.

You should instead flip the texture data before uploading it to OpenGL and keep your texture coordinates intact. If you do that, the same texture coordinates work for both image and FBO textures.

So the solution is to flip the bitmap before calling GLUtils.texImage2D and to write your vertices as

```
private final float[] mVerticesData =
    { 
        -1f, 1f, 0.0f, // Position 0
        0.0f, 1.0f, // TexCoord 0
        -1f, -1f, 0.0f, // Position 1
        0.0f, 0.0f, // TexCoord 1
        1f, -1f, 0.0f, // Position 2
        1.0f, 0.0f, // TexCoord 2
        1f, 1f, 0.0f, // Position 3
        1.0f, 1.0f // TexCoord 3
    };
```

Comment: thanks @msell  .That was the problem although now Im having  trouble with the touch coordinates. Wherever the user touches the screen the vertically oposite pixels gets modified ...

Answer (score 1):

> By the way rendering without creating frame buffer renders the texture correctely

I think it actually doesn't. With all transformations set to identity and texture coordinates matching vertex coordinates, i.e. S=X, T=Y, OpenGL assumes the origin of texture data to be in the lower left (with the noteable exception of cube maps, which are different beasts). Framebuffer color attachments, in your case your texture, agree upon that convention.

Your texture T coordinates are antiparallel to the Y vertex coordinates, which means in the case of an all identity transformation setup you flip it "upside down".

However most image file formats assume the origin in the upper left and if you upload such data as is to a OpenGL texture this adds another flip, and together with your texture coordinate flip both cancel out.

So it's very likely, that in face your regular texture code path is "flipped".

Comment: Im loading the texture from a bitmap: GLUtils.texImage2D(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, bitmap, 0);

Comment: @user1429893: So? What does bitmap contain. Where does bitmap assume its origin?